# it takes long time when i run javascript before window.onload

Tags: javascript, performance

I have the code for counting from 1 to n.

The following code it takes about 1s.

```js
const maxNum = Math.pow(2, 26);
const startTime = performance.now();
let result = 0;
for(let i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++) {
    result += i;
}
console.log(performance.now() - startTime);
```

But, once i put the same scripts in the window.onload, it takes about 65ms. Why the big difference?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const maxNum = Math.pow(2, 26);
    const startTime = performance.now();
    let result = 0;
    for(let i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++) {
        result += i;
    }
    console.log(performance.now() - startTime);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is because you're reassigning a reference on the top level, and at least in some environments, changing values on the global level is a lot more expensive than reassigning a reference to a non-global variable.

The below snippet does the same thing in an IIFE (which runs immediately), with the `result` that gets reassigned being on the top level. As you can see, it takes a similar (long) amount of time to process:

```js
let result = 0;
(() => {
  const maxNum = Math.pow(2, 26);
  const startTime = performance.now();
  for(let i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++) {
      result += i;
  }
  console.log(performance.now() - startTime);
})();
```

If you move the `let result = 0` inside the IIFE, the process will be much quicker, because then the reassigned variable is locally-scoped, rather than globally-scoped:

```js
(() => {
  let result = 0;
  const maxNum = Math.pow(2, 26);
  const startTime = performance.now();
  for(let i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++) {
      result += i;
  }
  console.log(performance.now() - startTime);
})();
```

It doesn't have anything to do with the operation being performed on load vs immediately - it just has to do with the fact that the variable binding you reassign `2 ** 26` times is globally-scoped.

Both Chrome and Firefox exhibit this behavior, though the difference is much larger in Chrome.

Comment: The difference is browser specific though - on the same machine: on firefox it's ~170ms vs ~90ms ... in chrome it's ~800-900ms vs ~90ms ... edge it's ~250ms vs ~170ms ... and IE won't run that code at all :p

Comment: I remember you pointing out something similar to this before. I know the *behavior* that results, but I have no idea *why* it is the way it is, do you know the reason for the difference?

Comment: It has to do with how javascript searches for variables in the *scope chain*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have some related article recommendation?

Comment: @unbregg Sorry, this is a rare topic. I've never seen anything really describing it.